# Можно ли присвоить пeременной в python значение оператора действия (например: ”+”, ”-” и т. д.)

Tags: python, if, переменные, типы-данных

Хочу использовать введенный в консоль знак действия напрямую через присваивание переменной его значения, а не через цикл `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если, я правильно Вас понял, то Вы можете использовать оператор `eval()`

Пример:

```py
command = 'print("test")'
eval(command)
```

---

**Важно: это очень небезопасный оператор, в рабочих проектах!**

Comment: Это решает мою задачу, но мне хотелось бы просто засунуть условный + в переменную

Answer (score 2):

Можно хранить карту, которая отображает строки с операторами в процедуры. Тогда можно обойтись без простыни из условных операторов:

```
ops = {
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b,
    '/': lambda a, b: a / b,
}

while True:
    s = input('> ')
    op = ops[s]
    print(2, s, 3, '=', op(2, 3))
```

> ```
> $ python ops.py
> > +
> 2 + 3 = 5
> > -
> 2 - 3 = -1
> > *
> 2 * 3 = 6
> > /
> 2 / 3 = 0.6666666666666666
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Есть ещё такая библиотека `operator`, там есть все основные операторы в виде готовых функций, их можно использовать так, например:

```py
from operator import add,sub,mul,truediv

str2op = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '*': mul,
    '/': truediv,
}
op_str = input()
op = str2op[op_str]

x, y = map(int, input().split())
print(op(x, y))
```

Пример ввода-вывода:

```
/
1 2
0.5
```